# allow non local/ remote connections in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac with a .net MVC application

Tags: .net, macos, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to see if I can hit a local application running on my Mac running osx 10.12.5 on a modernIE windows virtual machine running on Parallels (this instance of Parallels is running on the same Mac).

I realized that my .net app may not allow connections that aren't from localhost. In visual studio 2017 on the Mac is there a way to check if nonlocal connections are allowed?

On Windows I would check the applicationhost.config file, or check my IISExpress settings. It appears that [Kestrel is the cross platform .net core web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/) that VS2017 for Mac uses. I am not sure where to change the settings to allow nonlocal connections or remote connections to hit a web app it is running.

My application is ASP.NET MVC 5.2 the scafolded one if you click a .net mvc application from the menu on Visual Studio 2017 on MAC.

Edit: It appears Kestrel is the web server [looking through this link which may be helpful](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core#OntheMac:CreateaHOSTSentry)

Comment: Any suggestions for better tags please let me know or make edits. I am not sure the ones i picked are the best. I removed the IIS tag because I have yet to figure out if IISExpress is powering VS17 for mac.

Comment: Ended up using a workaround by serving my clientside application via node instead of .net which enabled me to hit it on the ModernIE windows VM.